# Play a random flv from a total of 5 flvs

Tags: actionscript-3, random, flash-cs5, flv

I need your help with Actionscipt3.0. To be honest I am reall noob in flash. I am more a 3D Designer so not a lot of flash ;)
Currently I have to create a website where some videos should be played automatically.

When a User opens the URL and lands on the page, a random video of a total of 5 should be played. When the video is finished, it should chose another video of the total of 5 videos.

So an example: It should chose one video of 5 videos. Play it, then it should chose 1 video of 4 videos, then it should chose 1 video of 3 videos..and so on. And after all 5 are played, it should repeat the process.

I hope someone here can help me with that...What i have sofar is this..

> var files:Array = [ "Sz01Puppet.flv", "Sz02Puppet.flv",
>   "Sz03Puppet.flv", "Sz04Puppet.flv", "Sz05Puppet.flv" ]; var
>   randomFiles:Array = [];
>
> var i:int; for (i=0; i
>       randomFiles.push(files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]);
>   }
>
> trace(randomFiles);

But its not working in any way..

Would be great if someone could help me out

Comment: you're logic looks ok, but you need also need to remove an item from the files array, otherwise you'll end up with duplicates, and that for loops looks a bit wrong...1 min

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you're nearly there.
Here's how the for loop should've been written:

```
var files:Array = [ "Sz01Puppet.flv", "Sz02Puppet.flv", "Sz03Puppet.flv", "Sz04Puppet.flv", "Sz05Puppet.flv" ]; var randomFiles:Array = [];
var i:int; 
for(i = 0 ; i < files.length; i++) randomFiles.push(files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]);
trace(randomFiles);
```

Still, you're note removing items form the array, so you'll have duplicates.

Here's an an example:

```
var files:Array = [ "Sz01Puppet.flv", "Sz02Puppet.flv", "Sz03Puppet.flv", "Sz04Puppet.flv", "Sz05Puppet.flv" ];
var shuffledFiles:Array = shuffleArray(files);
//quick test
var testTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
testTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,updateFile);
testTimer.start();

function updateFile(event:TimerEvent):void{
    if(shuffledFiles.length == 0) shuffledFiles = shuffleArray(files);//all files played, repeat process
    trace('play file',shuffledFiles[0]);
    shuffledFiles.shift();
}
function shuffleArray(source:Array,clone:Boolean = true):Array {
    var output:Array = [];
    var input:Array = clone ? [].concat(source) : source;//clone ? preserve orignal items by making a copy for shuffling, or not
    while(input.length) output.push(input.splice(int(Math.random() * input.length-1),1)[0]);
    return output;
}
```

Goodluck

Comment: Thank you George! It seems to work. I get a never ending loop, which is what i want. I have now the 5 FLVs, but how do i get the actionscript to work, and render out a file which plays all 5 flvs randomly? Which i then can implement to my website?

Comment: Another thing which would help me..Do I have to place my 5 flvs to the stage, or can they stay in the library? I have almost no experience in flash so you guys are really a great help for me. 

@Mark

Comment: @arvidurs No worries! I imagine by "plays all 5 flvs" you mean sequentially, not simultaneously :) It depends on your website & its setup.I would say the easiest way would be [using FLVPlayback](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/flvplayback_component.html). Once you've got your FLVPlayback with an instance name and the skin you need, set the flv path as the source( yourFLVPlayer.source = yourRandomFLVPath). If you're site is html mostly, then it might be worth checking out SWFObject/FlashVars/ExternalInterface so you can control videos without recompiling the swf all the time.

Comment: Could I add you on skype? They should play one after the other. (this is what the page looks now http://www.music-puppets.com/ but I want all 5 videos of them to play randomly after each other. )

Comment: Okay I have got the FLVPlayback on the Stage. In the source tab, should I add "Sz01Puppet.flv", create a new FLVPlayback and add "Sz02Puppet.flv" and so on? Or what file should I add in the source tab in the FLVPlayback?

what should I write in the  " = clone ? " code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *Array.sort()* function to sort it randomly.

```
// random sort function
function shuffle(a:*, b:*):int 
{
    return int(Math.random() * 2) - 1;
}

var files:Array = ["Sz01Puppet.flv", "Sz02Puppet.flv", "Sz03Puppet.flv", "Sz04Puppet.flv", "Sz05Puppet.flv"];

var randomFiles:Array = files.sort(shuffle); // get a new instance of the array which is sorted

trace(randomFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://flassari.is/2009/04/as3-array-shuffle/) is one way to do it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your help! I will be testing it in a few hours. And will reply to you :) Am really glad for your support..